# Массив шаблонов

Tags: c++, qt, шаблоны-с++

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь понять как реализовать класс для кастомного протокола обмена данными. 
Я обмениваюсь с девайсом подобными пакетами:

```
AB 01 02 04 B8 07 0D 07 FE 
AB 01 02 04 99 07 1D 07 AF 
AB 01 02 04 78 07 22 07 45 
AB 01 02 | 04       | 19 07     | 15 07 BD A5 | B3
            uint8_t     uint16_t    float
```

Исходя из адреса девайса и номера команды я могу понять, в каком месте посылки лежат данные того или иного типа (uint8_t, float, int, и т.д.).

Соответственно, я хочу сделать универсальный класс для девайсов. После создания объектов класса настраивать их, задавая типы данных, количество данных, команду и т.д., а дальше просто заполнять данными, оно само конвертируется в массив байт в зависимости от текущего типа данных и отправит посылку на порт. То же самое со чтением данных с порта.

Но мне нужно как-то запомнить в какой последовательности и какие данные лежат. Решил сделать шаблонный класс для разных типов данных и ими заполнять вектор. Т.е. в определенной ячейке вектора лежит объект класса, у которого известен тип данных, соответственно, размер, и можно заодно человеческие данные туда положить. Но вот как-то не хочет это работать.

Сырые прототипы:

```
class AbstractField{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractField(){}
    virtual int getSize(){}
};

template<class T>
class DataType:public AbstractField{
    T value;
    union {
        T data;
        uint8_t bytes[sizeof(T)];
    } r2b; //result to byte array
public:
    T dataCalc(){

    }
    virtual int getSize(){
        return sizeof(value);
    }
};

//
class Device: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    ComPort *port;
    int command;
    QVector<AbstractField*> w_data;
    QVector<AbstractField*> r_data;
    QVector<DataType<int>> test;
public:
    Device(int command = 0x00);
    ~Device(){}
    void setPort(ComPort *port);

    void setWDataType(AbstractField *dataType, int count);
    void setRDataType(AbstractField *dataType, int count);
    void setData(int i, AbstractField *data);
    AbstractField *getRData(int i);
    void send();
private slots:
    void packageAnalysis(QByteArray data);
};
```

Сам вопрос: каким путем еще можно решить мою проблему и если моя идея неплохая, то как ее довести до ума?

**Edit 1 (Краткое описание проблемы)**

Девайс отправляет такой пакет в шестнадцатеричной системе

```
AB 01 02 04 19 07 15 07 BD A5 B3
```

Здесь `04` - uint8_t, `19 07` - uint16_t, `15 07 BD A5` - float. Девайсы могут быть разными, соответственно посылки могут быть разной длины и типов данных.

Я хочу сделать единый класс `Device`, в котором будет храниться вектор `w_data` (для записи и `r_data` для чтения) объектов `DataType`.

Например,

```
QVector<DataType> w_data;
w_data[0]; //- это DataType<uint8_t>
w_data[1]; //- это DataType<uint16_t>
```

Я не могу просто так создать вектор объектов шаблонного класса, поэтому пришлось подсовывать ссылку на виртуальный базовый класс `AbstractField`.

Comment: Вы не сможете создавать обькты  AbstractField, а вектора с обьектами такого типа тем более... Ну а разобраться в коде уже не остались силы -  переутомился

Comment: Справедливое замечание. Я уже понял, что AbstractField везде должен быть ссылкой, куда я буду подсовывать ссылки на класс-наследник, т.е. Device. Наследование было сделано из-за того, что я не могу создать вектор объектов шаблонного класса. Собственно, как мне теперь работать с методами класса-наследника через указатель на базовый класс я пока не понимаю..

Comment: читайте в учебнике раздел наследование классов и абстрактные классы

Comment: Не хочу показаться глупым, но шаблонный тип T доступен только в классе Device, и как мне с этим T работать из абстрактного класса, который не может быть шаблонным из-за вектора?

Comment: У вас ошибки с самого начала. Такое   virtual ~AbstractField() = 0; определение  только приведет потом к неопределенной ссыльке. Не приравнивайте нулю деструктор... Нужно так:  virtual ~AbstractField() = deffult

Comment: Глупо не покажетесь, глупо, когда не знаете и не спрашиваете. Но исходя из  того, что вы написали и говорите, я  вам рекомендую читать литературу, поскольку в чате я вам не обьясню целый раздел языка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо за исправления, но код я выложил, чтобы хоть как-то попытаться описать проблему. Сейчас перезалил немного исправленный код. Тем не менее, проблема остается актуальной: я хочу сделать вектор объектов шаблонного класса. Я могу это сделать только через указатель на базовый (не шаблонный), но мне нужны методы класса-наследника, которые используют тип T (например, T dataCalc()). А этот тип недоступен в базовом классе.

Comment: вы сделали хорошую работу и подошли ближе к истине, но у меня не было времени вам отвечать, за что извеняюсь. Теперь все расскажу на примере

Answer (score 1):

```
Если же у вас есть абстрактный базовый класс, то весь интерфейс нужно содержать в нем, чтобы можно было бы через указатель класса вызвать все нужные функции. Так как вы проделали хорошую работу в сторону улучшения:
```

Я  приведу пример реализации, а вы старайтесь понять логику и написать  свою версию так, как удобней для решения вашей задачи

```
using namespace std;
// если вы получаете данные в виде строки
using Type = string;
class AbstractField{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractField() = default;
    virtual int getSize() = 0;
    virtual void read(const Type&) = 0;
    virtual void send() const = 0;
    // и другие все функции, которые нужно вызвать через AbstractField*
};    
template<size_t sz>
class DataType:public AbstractField{
    // тут  обьект, во что храним полученные данные.
    //Это может быть строка или вектор, массив: все что вам удобно
    using T = vector<uint16_t>;  // если вы хотите хранить в векторе данные
    T val;
public:
    T dataCalc(){}
    // определяем все виртуальные функции
    // спецификатор virtual не обязательно указывать: компилятор сам поймет
    int getSize(){ return sz; }
    // read реализуем так, чтобы  строго прочитать только sz штук данных
    void read(const Type&) {}
    void send() const {}
    //...    
};
// вы даже можете написать предикат, по которому найдете нужный элемент
// в стандартных альгоритмах (или свооих)
bool predicat(AbstractField* pa, size_t k)
{      return  pa->getSize() == k;  }

int main()
{        
    AbstractField* p = new DataType<1>();
    string s;
    p->read(s);
    p->send();
    // например
     p = new DataType<3>();
    vector<int> v(p->getSize());
    // это вектор с количеством элементов размера обьекта DataType
    // на что указывет  AbstractField* p
    //...
    cout << v.size() <<endl; // 3
    vector<AbstractField*> va;
    va.emplace_back(p);
    if(predicat(va[0], 3))
        cout << "ok";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: P.S. аргумент шаблона   является индикатором на количества  содержащихся в  обьекте данных

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение! Добавил и свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataType: AbstractField {...}
```

это описание эквивалентно

```
class DataType: private AbstractField {...}
```

т.к. права доступа при наследовании в классах по умолчанию - private. Замените на public, и сможете положить по указателю на базовый класс объект класса, наследуемого от AbstractField.

Comment: @MaratGareev Ну тут есть несколько вариантов. Либо вы уходите от шаблонов ( во всяком случае от шаблонного возвращаемого значения) и возвращаете какой-нибудь `QVariant` . Либо немного измените архитектуру. Сделайте два виртуальных метода у AbstractField: `read_from_array(const std::vector<uint8_t>& bytes, size_t& offset)` и `write_to_array(const std::vector<uint8_t>& bytes, size_t& offset)`, которые будут производить запись в конечный буффер, или же чтение из него. Увы, при чтении значения из DataType без приведения типов вряд ли можно обойтись.

Comment: Я могу сделать вектор из QVariant, записать-то я запишу, но как оттуда выдернуть именно то, что я записал, непонятно. Т.е. запишу в QVariant восьмибитное целое число, а могу выдернуть обратно хоть строку, хоть float. По поводу второго: я думал о том, чтобы запоминать размеры данных посылки. Например, [2, 2, 4], т.е. я знаю, что сначала идет 2 байта 2 раза, потом 4 байта. Но четырехбайтным может быть как float, так и целое.

Comment: @MaratGareev `QVariant::type()` даст вам знания и типе. Если я вас правильно понял, вам заранее известна структура пакета. Поэтому вы можете без особых усилий и читать данные в этой последовательности, т.е. вам не особо то и нужны размеры данных,  если заранее известны конкретные типы

Answer (score 0):

Я долго и мучительно пытался написать класс, который умел бы работать со всеми типами данных автоматически. Но в итоге пришел к выводу, что без сравнения типа данных не обойтись..

Код класса:

*protocol.h*

```
class Device: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    ComPort *port;
    int command;
    QVector<QVariant> w_data;
    QVector<QVariant> r_data;
public:
    Device(int command = 0x00);
    ~Device(){}
    void setPort(ComPort *port);

    void setWDataType(QVariant dataType, int count);
    void setRDataType(QVariant dataType, int count);
    void setWData(int i, QVariant data);
    QVariant getRData(int i);
    void send();
private slots:
    void packageAnalysis(QByteArray data);
signals:
    void dataReady();
};
```

*protocol.cpp*

```
Device::Device(int command)
{
    this->command = command;
}

void Device::setPort(ComPort *port)
{
    this->port = port;
    connect(this->port, SIGNAL(packageReady(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(packageAnalysis(QByteArray)));
}

void Device::setWDataType(QVariant dataType, int count)
{
    while (count){
        w_data.append(dataType);
        count--;
    }
}

void Device::setRDataType(QVariant dataType, int count)
{
    while (count){
        r_data.append(dataType);
        count--;
    }
}

void Device::setWData(int i, QVariant data)
{
    if (data.convert(w_data[i].type())){
        w_data[i] = data;
    }
}

QVariant Device::getRData(int i)
{
    return r_data[i];
}

void Device::send()
{
    int sizeOfData = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w_data.size(); i++){
        sizeOfData += QMetaType::sizeOf(w_data[i].type());
    }
    QByteArray tx_data;
    tx_data.append(0xAB);
    tx_data.append(0x01);
    tx_data.append(command);
    tx_data.append(sizeOfData);

    for (int i = 0; i < w_data.size(); i++){
        uint8_t array[QMetaType::sizeOf(w_data[i].type())];
        switch (static_cast<QMetaType::Type>(w_data[i].type())) {
        case QMetaType::UShort: case QMetaType::UChar:{ //uint16_t  uint8_t
            uint16_t data = w_data[i].toInt();
            memcpy(array, &data, sizeof(array));
            break;
        }
        case QMetaType::Float:{ //float
            float data = w_data[i].toFloat();
            memcpy(array, &data, sizeof(array));
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(array); k++){
            tx_data.append(array[k]);
        }
    }
    uint8_t crc = 0x00;
    for (int i = tx_data.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
        crc -= tx_data[i];
    tx_data.append(crc);
    port->write(tx_data);
}

void Device::packageAnalysis(QByteArray data)
{
    if (data[2] == command){ //если команда посылки принадлежит текущему девайсу
        int currentPos = 4; //текущая позиция в посылке
        for (int i = 0; i < r_data.size(); i++){
            uint8_t array[QMetaType::sizeOf(r_data[i].type())];
            for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(array); k++){
                array[k] = data[currentPos++];
            }
            switch (static_cast<QMetaType::Type>(r_data[i].type())) {
            case QMetaType::UChar: { //uint8_t
                uint8_t data;
                memcpy(&data, array, sizeof(array));
                r_data[i] = QVariant::fromValue(data);
                break;
            }
            case QMetaType::UShort: { //uint16_t
                uint16_t data;
                memcpy(&data, array, sizeof(array));
                r_data[i] = QVariant::fromValue(data);
                break;
            }
            case QMetaType::Float:{ //float
                float data;
                memcpy(&data, array, sizeof(array));
                r_data[i] = QVariant::fromValue(data);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
            }
            //qDebug() << "Data: " << r_data[i].toString();
        }
        emit dataReady();
    }
}
```

Как видно, не удалось избежать *switch - case*'ов.

Используется так:

```
Device servos{0x01};
Device touch{0x02};
Device manualMode{0x03};

servos.setPort(&port);
touch.setPort(&port);
manualMode.setPort(&port);

servos.setWDataType(QVariant(QMetaType::UShort, nullptr), 4);
servos.setWDataType(QVariant(QMetaType::Float, nullptr), 1);
//теперь servos пакует в посылку 4 числа uint16_t, затем 1 число float
//остается только записывать данные с помощью setWData и отправлять посылку на порт

touch.setRDataType(QVariant(QMetaType::UShort, nullptr), 2);
//теперь touch ждет свою посылку, зная, что там 2 числа в uint16_t
//при чтении данных с порта данные сами заполняться в вектор
//остается их только прочитать по индексу

manualMode.setWDataType(QVariant(QMetaType::UChar, nullptr), 1);

servos.setWData(0, 150);
servos.send();
```

В целом, это то, чего я хотел добиться. Но пытался сделать так, чтобы не нужно было вручную добавлять новые типы данных. Видимо, в плюсах это нереализуемо.

Остается только добавить всевозможные проверки на размерность данных, чтобы не выйти за пределы вектора.